# Effect to pointers after reversing a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

In the following code with a stringy Linked List, I created 2 pointers, *fast* and *slow*. I move fast pointer to the end and slow pointer to the middle. I then reversed the right half.

```java
public void test(ListNode head) {
    ListNode fast = head, slow = head;
    while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
        fast = fast.next.next;  //to the end of the list
        slow = slow.next;   //to the middle
    }
    slow = reverse(slow);  
    fast = head;   
    while (fast != null) {
        System.out.println(fast.val); //fast pointer only goes until the middle of the list
        fast=fast.next;
    }
    return true;
}
public ListNode reverse(ListNode head) {
    ListNode prev = null;
    while (head != null) {
        ListNode next = head.next;
        head.next = prev;
        prev = head;
        head = next;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

What I don't understand is that as soon as I reversed the right half, fast pointer only has access to elements until the middle of the LinkedList.

For example, let's say the LinkedList has `1->2->4->8->5`. After reverse(slow), the slow pointer points to `5->8->4`, which is good. However, now the fast pointer points to `1->2->4`, which I don't understand why. Why doesn't it have access to `8` and `5`? What did the reverse method do to the fast pointer?

Comment: Did you run your code through a debugger already?

Comment: Yes many times @Thomas

Comment: One problem is that the value of the node directly in front of `slow` will still reference its original "next", i.e. 2 will still reference 4 even though you're returning 5 from `reverse()`. Thus you'll need to keep track of the `slow - 1` and set its "next" after `reverse()` or make it a doubly linked list and set the "prev" reference accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Your Final linked list is `1->2->4<-8<-5` and `4->(null)`. You should set the next of 2 to `2->5` somewhere which will solve the problem.